# zenity file handling to python

Tags: python, bash, zenity

I wanted to speed up my subtitle creation from videos by using Zenity.
I have zero experience with Python and some with Zenity.
So I did:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop
file="$(zenity --title "Video to subtitles:         Select a File to convert" --file- selection )"
wavfile="$(zenity --file-selection --save --confirm-overwrite --filename="${file%.*}.wav")"
srtfile="$(zenity --file-selection --save --confirm-overwrite --filename="${file%.*}.srt")"
ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 1 "$wavfile"
cd ~/vosk-api/python/example
time python3 ./test_srt.py "$wavfile" > "$srtfile"
zenity --info --text "Conversion Completed"
```

Of course, I forgot the last bit uses python to do the conversion, and Python does not get along with bash, so I get zero output.

Any takers?
Yours hopefully,
Fitch

Answer (score 0):

False alarm.
It works fine.
I forgot to unzip the vosk model.
So the bottom part now reads:

```
  unzip vosk-model-small-en-us-0.3.zip
  mv vosk-model-small-en-us-0.3 model
  time python3 ./test_srt.py "$wavfile" > "$srtfile"
  zenity --info --text "Conversion Completed"
```

Sorry about that.